# Is there any way to link to a specific paragraph on an external web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I guess my question can be reduced to "How do I direct a browser to go to a specific html tag or group of words on a certain page in Internet"?

I do not expect that to be done via a hyper link but rather via a script or something. Having the remote web page in an iframe on my page is acceptable

```js
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
myIframe.onload = function(){
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(100,100);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://tinyurl.com/"  style='height: 300px; width: 300px;'  ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need is an suggestion on how to scroll or move the focus in the iframe to the paragraph that I need. Above is the only thing that I could come up with but it does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess one way to do it is by using an annotation service, here is an example: 
http://marker.to/CVonrw

You could either embed that in an iframe or just open the link in a new page (that is how I would use it)

The service adds a div to your page, here is how exactly to link to that highlight at the bottom of the page
http://marker.to/CVonrw#textmarker_1

Answer (score 0):

Unless the site provides an anchor you can link to, this is impossible.

The Same Origin Policy prevents you manipulating the third-party document with JavaScript.

Comment: How about other methods?  JavaScript  is not mandatory, it could be anything else

Comment: I refer you back to the first sentence of this answer.